# Convert user understandable date time format string to strptime understandable format string

Tags: python, datetime-format

How can I convert `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, `"HH:mm"`, `"dd-MMM-yy"`, `"M/d/yyyy"` etc., to `"%d/%m/%Y"`, `"%H:%M"`, `"%d-%b-%y"` or `"%m/%d/%Y"` etc?

Comment: Interesting, but do you want this to work for any valid `datetime` ?

Comment: @jamylak I didn't understand your question. Any example of an invalid `datetime`?

Comment: I'm asking if you want to support the whole table here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @jamylak not the whole table, just those which have equivalent user understandable representations. And while I am at it, what would be the equivalent of `"%j"`?

Comment: `ddd` is what you mean??

Comment: @jamylak yup. Didn't know about that.

Comment: The input format looks like ICU date format; you could [pass it to `icu.SimpleDateFormat`, to parse a date string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29548727/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I wanted to convert, e.g., the actual "dd/mm/yyyy" to "%d/%m/%Y" not "09/05/2015".

Comment: @BleedingFingers: I understand it that is why I've posted a *comment*, not an *answer*. You could use ICU API *instead of* strptime-based API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extend `replacements` to cover all possible user date time formats (you may also edit this answer to include them here)

```
import re

replacements = {
    r'dd': '%d',
    r'd': '%d',
    r'MM': '%m',
    r'M': '%m',
    r'yyyy': '%Y',
    r'HH': '%H',
    r'mm': '%M',
    r'MMM': '%b',
    r'yy': '%Y',
}

def fn(match):
    return replacements[match.group()]

def F(text):
    pat = '|'.join(r'\b' + re.escape(k) + r'\b' for k in replacements)
    return re.sub(pat, fn, text)

>>> F("dd/MM/yyyy")
'%d/%m/%Y'
>>> F("HH:mm")
'%H:%M'
>>> F("dd-MMM-yy")
'%d-%b-%Y'
>>> F("M/d/yyyy")
'%m/%d/%Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

change  the format of date time

import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-05-24", "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 24, 0, 0)

d.format("%d.%b.%Y")
'24-May-2013'

The format function in put before and after two underscore